# How I can remove element in array of map in firebase SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have struct in firebase (in picture) how I can remove element where date = my date.

```
let removeExistingBookingTime: [String : Any] = ["booking_days" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([["date" : bookingDay.date]])]
```

But it is not work

[image]

Comment: There is no simple query for this.  You have to read the document, iterate the array field values, remove the matching objects from memory, then write the modified array back to the document.

Comment: I think this is not what I need.
Perhaps needed to change struct of Data? What i need to do: I want to add and remove the booking time for selected date.
For exemplee use case: Customer select Date and time in Author calendar and make order, and i set this Date and time to this structure and this time not avaible for anothe booking, but Author can cansele the order and need to remove this Date and time or just time for sturct

Comment: Instead of a map you should try a sub collection